# cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:230 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'response.profileObj' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-google-login

I keep getting this error and I don't know what is causing it.

```
const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const responseGoogle = (response) => {
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.profileObj));

    const { name, googleId, imageUrl } = response.profileObj;
    const doc = {
      _id: googleId,
      _type: "user",
      userName: name,
      image: imageUrl,
    };
    client.createIfNotExists(doc).then(() => {
      navigate("/", { replace: true });
    });
  };
```

If I make this change `const { name, googleId, imageUrl } = response.profileObj ?? {};`

then i get this: `Uncaught Error: createIfNotExists() requires that the document contains an ID ("_id" property)`

Any Idea of what I'm missing?

Comment: Seems your `response.profileObj` is getting `null` or `undefined`. You'll get `undefined` when you do `const {name} = {}` so you are getting that error. Try to add an if condition and execute those statements when the `profileObj` have data

Comment: I tried but doesn't solve the problem. I can't log in with google and a keep getting 401 errors.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when I was trying to do this. In my case I found out that the googleId is sometimes empty and causes this type of error. I solved it by putting an IF statement before declaring in your case the doc const and simply just checking if the googleId is empty.. Tell me if that works for you, if not I am more than happy to help.